# Disproportionality between JFrame within the IDE and the same running

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

My problem is not so big, but it is annoying.

See my `JFrame` within my IDE (Netbeans 12.6):

[Frame within IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfq3P.png)

(Pay attention to the distance of the text fields)

Now, see the same frame running:

[Frame running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOUFP.png)

Do you see the difference? This is too uncomfortable.

What do I do to make the distance of the elements equal in my running frame?

PS: the frame is set as non-resizable (maybe this info is useful).

Comment: For more help please show the relevant code. Try calling `pack();` at the end of your JFrame/Window initilization method, which should force the form to size correctly to fit everything correctly. This may also be caused by a disconnect between a minimum and preferred size of a component, but we can't tell that without seeing code.

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: Also the font is different: "Info" has a different capital I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used NetBeans IDE, let alone its [GUI builder](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html), before today. It is actually quite powerful. Even though it allows someone who doesn't know [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) to create a working application, I believe its real intent is to save experienced programmers from writing a lot of boilerplate code that *Swing* applications require. In other words, in order to get the most out of NetBeans GUI builder, you need to have a thorough knowledge of *Swing* and that only comes from experience by writing lots of *Swing* code (and not having the GUI builder generate the code for you). I would say that NetBeans GUI builder is for the *Swing* master and not for the *Swing* apprentice.

By default, NetBeans GUI builder uses [GroupLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) which I assume is the layout manager used in your code but that seems to be giving you a problem – otherwise you wouldn't have posted your question. Hence you need to use nested `JPanel`s with appropriate layout managers for each `JPanel` – which is what I did.

Here is a screen capture of NetBeans IDE showing the hierarchy of the nested panels.

[image: NetBeans GUI builder]

The layout manager for [content pane of] `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. As you can see in the "tree" in the bottom left corner of the above image, `JFrame` contains three panels, namely `topPanel` (whose layout manager is `BoxLayout`), `resultPanel` and `bottomPanel` (which both have `FlowLayout` as their layout manager). Hopefully you will now be able to understand the rest of the "tree".

Now to your problem regarding the space between the `JTextField`s in the top part of the GUI. As you can see, I used [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) since it will ensure that the locations of the text fields, relative to each other, will remain constant. Note that there are probably other layout managers that will also give you the same result but I will let you investigate other options if you so desire. Maybe look at [JGoodies FormLayout](https://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/). Note that I have never used it myself.

And so to complete this answer, here is the code (which was entirely generated by NetBeans). I did, however, comment out the code that sets the [look-and-feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html). Also, the below code only creates and displays the GUI. The `JButton`s do nothing when you click on them.

```java
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */
package guibuild;

public class NbGuiBld extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NbGuiBld
     */
    public NbGuiBld() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        buttonGroup = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        topPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        dataPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        formPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        nameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        nameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        weightLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        weightTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        heightLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        heightTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        genderPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        maleRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        femaleRadioButton = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        buttonsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        clearButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        calculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        resultPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        bottomPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("BMI Calculator");

        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(538, 220));
        topPanel.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(topPanel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        dataPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Personal Info"));
        dataPanel.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(dataPanel, javax.swing.BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        formPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(526, 130));
        formPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        nameLabel.setText("Enter your name:");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 5, 40);
        formPanel.add(nameLabel, gridBagConstraints);

        nameTextField.setColumns(15);
        nameTextField.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(171, 22));
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 10, 40);
        formPanel.add(nameTextField, gridBagConstraints);

        weightLabel.setText("Enter your weight (kg):");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 5, 40);
        formPanel.add(weightLabel, gridBagConstraints);

        weightTextField.setColumns(10);
        weightTextField.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(116, 22));
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 10, 40);
        formPanel.add(weightTextField, gridBagConstraints);

        heightLabel.setText("Enter your height (cm):");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        formPanel.add(heightLabel, gridBagConstraints);

        heightTextField.setColumns(10);
        heightTextField.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(116, 22));
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
        formPanel.add(heightTextField, gridBagConstraints);

        dataPanel.add(formPanel);

        genderPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout(1, 20, 5));

        buttonGroup.add(maleRadioButton);
        maleRadioButton.setText("male");
        genderPanel.add(maleRadioButton);

        buttonGroup.add(femaleRadioButton);
        femaleRadioButton.setText("female");
        genderPanel.add(femaleRadioButton);

        dataPanel.add(genderPanel);

        topPanel.add(dataPanel);

        buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(824, 70));
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout(1, 20, 5));

        clearButton.setText("Clear");
        buttonsPanel.add(clearButton);

        calculateButton.setText("Calculate");
        buttonsPanel.add(calculateButton);

        topPanel.add(buttonsPanel);

        getContentPane().add(topPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        resultPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Result"));

        jTextArea1.setColumns(60);
        jTextArea1.setRows(15);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        resultPanel.add(jScrollPane1);

        getContentPane().add(resultPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        bottomPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout(4));

        exitButton.setText("Exit");
        bottomPanel.add(exitButton);

        getContentPane().add(bottomPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NbGuiBld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NbGuiBld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NbGuiBld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NbGuiBld.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         */
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NbGuiBld().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel bottomPanel;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
    private javax.swing.JPanel buttonsPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton calculateButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton clearButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel dataPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton femaleRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel formPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel genderPanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel heightLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField heightTextField;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton maleRadioButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField nameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JPanel resultPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel topPanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel weightLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField weightTextField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

And this is how it looks when I run the above code.

[image: Running app]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! You helped me twice! Both solved my problem and made me understand that I can't start with GUI builder; I should start writing the codes... I have a Java course that also teaches JavaFX, but I haven't gotten there yet. Now I will be able to learn the right way (without wanting to start with GUI Builders). I know it's tiring to write each line, but is the correct way. Anyway, thank you!